# adding hover to all element on page

Tags: jquery, hover, this

I need to add a Hover event to all the elements on the page, i am doing that like this:

```
$("*").hover(
      function () {
              $(this).addClass('hoverElem'); ;
      },
      function () {
              $(this).removeClass('hoverElem');
      }
    );
```

now i need to have it do the event on every element but not on the body element, any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: if I understand you correctly and if your code above works, you can do something like this: "$('body *').hover( .....". I think that adjustment should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting all elements under body:

```
$("body *").hover(...)
```

Comment: Thank you but it didnt work, i have the page in a iframe, maybe thats why it doesnt work? any other ideas?

Comment: It worked now, but its funny some site in the iframe work and some dont.

Answer (score 1):

`$('body *').hover(function() {
  // ...
});`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in thihttp://jsfiddle.net/D42d5/

you can use the not selector so the selector could look something like:

```
    $("*:not(body)").hover(
      function () {
              $(this).addClass('hoverElem'); ;
      },
      function () {
              $(this).removeClass('hoverElem');
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it different way:

```
$("#IframeID").contents().find("body *").hover(
      function () {
              $(this).addClass('hoverElem');
      },
      function () {
              $(this).removeClass('hoverElem');
      }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use bind and unbind.

Like this

```
     $("*").bind('hover', function() {
  //do something
});    
 $("body").unbind('hover', function() {
  //do something
});
```